# Python - JSON convertion with Pandas to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm working with a JSON file that has nested objects like this.
The data is divided in to Columns and rows.

The columns data should be in separate columns and in the rows object, the numbers inside it should be associated with the respective columns, like so:

- Depth: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- Page_Count: 1, 661, 16773, etc

So far I haven't been able to convert the file into that format, how can I go about doing this?

```js
 {
      "aggs": [
        {
          "cols": [
            "depth",
            "page_count"
          ],
          "rows": [
            [
              1,
              1
            ],
            [
              2,
              661
            ],
            [
              3,
              16773
            ],
            [
              4,
              7078
            ],
            [
              5,
              221
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The final product should look something like this:

```
    depth | page_count
    -----:|----------:
        1 |          1
        2 |        661
        3 |      16773
        4 |       7078
        5 |        221
```

Comment: What have you tried and what happened? Also please can you try to clarify your description of how the data is arranged and how you want it to be arranged.

Comment: The data inside "cols" are individual columns in a CSV file.
The data inside "rows" is assigned to the columns.
This is the configuration: Depth 1 2 3 4 5 Page_Count 1, 661, 16773

Comment: @Stuart I've updated the final line of the post with an image of what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These json formats end up being nested dicts, so I handled it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

x =  {
  "aggs": [
    {
      "cols": [
        "depth",
        "page_count"
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          1,
          1
        ],
        [
          2,
          661
        ],
        [
          3,
          16773
        ],
        [
          4,
          7078
        ],
        [
          5,
          221
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}

dfrows = []
dfcolumns = []
for y,z in x.items(): # x.items() is a nested dict with aggs is outer key x and z is list as the value of aggs:
    for a in z: # a accesses the inner dict in the list
        for j,k in a.items(): # key, value of rows and cols in inner dict
            if j == 'rows':
                dfrows.append(k) # make list of list of row values
            if j == 'cols':
                dfcolumns.append(k) # make list of list of column names

rows_flat_list = [item for x in dfrows for item in x] # flatten out list
columns_flat_list = [item for x in dfcolumns for item in x] # flatten out list

dfJson = pd.DataFrame(data = rows_flat_list, columns= columns_flat_list) # create df

dfJson.to_csv('./dfJson.csv', index=False) # write to csv
```

output csv file looks like (or if you open with excel it is an excelfile format):

```
depth,page_count
1,1
2,661
3,16773
4,7078
5,221
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm getting  dfJson not define when I try this solution!

Comment: If you copied it directly, maybe try it again. Inside the for loop there was an indentation issue that I just fixed (one indent had one space less than it should). I just ran the code again and it is working fine for me!

Comment: I would love to figure this out and mark it as the right answer, because I'm having so many  issues with this and your answer is the best one so far!

Comment: The error seems to be here:
if j == 'cols':
                dfJson.columns = k # make cols columns names

dfJson.to_csv('./Desktop/dfJson.csv', index=False)

Comment: What happens if you `print(dfJson)` inside of the last if statement, like `if j == 'cols': dfJson.columns = k print(dfJson)`

Comment: try printing dfJson in the last if statement to see if it populates a df, if so we can write out the df to csv in that if statement and I think it would be fine.

Comment: if j == 'cols': dfJson.columns = k print(dfJson)

this gives invalid syntax

also tried: if j == 'cols':
                print(dfJson)
but this gives dfJson not defined

Comment: I do not know why it is not defining for you. that is strange!

Comment: I mean put `print(dfJson)` on its own line underneath the dfJson.columns = k statement. That would not be invalid syntax

Comment: Can I contact you through some chat? or by e-mail?
mine is: guschain1@outlook.pt

Comment: I edited my answer, try it and if it doesn't work we can use the chat on here.

Comment: Yes, I tried to print, like so:

if j == 'rows':
                dfJson = pd.DataFrame(k) # make rows the row values
            if j == 'cols':
                dfJson.columns = k
                print(dfJson)

Comment: Still not defined with the new code edited, I can't move to chat, it seems I don't have enough reputation

Comment: I sent email! :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see `pandas.read_json` cannot deal with data in this format, so you have to read it in using `json.loads` (or `json.load` from a file) first.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data = """{"aggs": [{"rows": [[1, 1], [2, 661], [3, 16773], [4, 7078], 
        [5, 221]], "cols": ["depth", "page_count"]}]}"""

main_data = json.loads(data)["aggs"][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=main_data['cols'], data=main_data['rows'])
df.to_csv("my_file.csv")
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but I get this error with my File TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Then your data is probably a dict to start with? So no need for `json.loads`

Answer (score 0):

This example takes the first `aggs` value, and converts it to `csv`

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data = json.loads(json_text)['aggs'][0]
pd.DataFrame(data['rows'], columns = data['cols']).to_csv('output.csv')
```

Just loop over `aggs` if you expect more than one table per `json_text`

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but I get this error with my File TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: You used a `dict` for `json_text` and not a string as your question suggests. just replace `json.loads(json_text)` with only `json_text`